# Time complexity of probabilistic algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, probability

The game is simple: a program has to 'guess' some given n such that 1 < n < N, where n and N are positive integers.
Assuming I'm using a true random number generator function ( rng() ) to generate the computer's 'guess', the probability that it will 'guess' the given n at any try is 1/N.

Example pseudo-code:

```
n = a // we assign some positive integer value to n

N = b // we assign some positive integer value to N

check loop
{
   if rng(N) = n
      print some success message
      exit program
   else 
      back to the beginning of the check loop
}
```

OK, I'm interested in how do I determine the time complexity (the upper bound especially) of this algorithm? I'm kind of confused. How does the probability aspect affect this? If I understand correctly, the worst case scenario (in theory) is that the program runs forever?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the code just randomly guesses each time (possibly repeating a guess) ?

Comment: If the computer can repeat, then it certainly may run forever (though this is a low probability event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if theoretically your program can run forever, complexity here is **O(n)** - because doubling n you're halving probability of guessing particular value on every step, thus doubling number of steps. Even if program could run *forever* with given n, it would run *twice forever* if n is 2 times bigger.

Complexity in O notation doesn't tell you how many operations will be performed. It tells you **how number of operations depends on input size**.

Comment: Do you have any references for this?  It is my understanding that the probabilistic algorithm would still need to be guaranteed to finish in O(N) steps for it to be considered O(N).  In other words, for this example, it would need to not repeat guesses.

Comment: @mbeckish you're absolutely right. I assumed that if probability of performing at least any given number of iterations for input *n* is *p*, for input *2n* it is *2p*. It doesn't strictly apply to O-notation definition since constant *c* can be infinite here. It would be very helpful if you edit this answer or post your own, explaining shortly why O-notations cannot be applied to any randomized algorithm.

Comment: @vdangre if repeating guesses are disallowed, it's definitely O(n). Average case will perform n/2 iterations => O(n), worst n iterations => O(n).

Comment: @AlexSalauyou im currently working on a problem concerning this, but wouldnt doubling n result in the halfing of p and thus the doubling of c?